# Seat reservations for (recurring) events on given days

Tags: 6, ubercart, entities, payment-gateways

I would like to let my users **reserve *seats*** (or a whole table) for events, and **pay for the reservation via PayPal**.

Different performances/shows would be advertised, users could choose which tables or seats they would like to reserve. A theater OR bar, restaurant, etc. would have "fix" seats and tables, so they would not change (or just rarely); **events can be repetitive/recurring** (e.g. concerts) - in some cases, locations can remain the same too, so only the date changes (e.g. a concert played in Example Bar 3 times a month); but one event can be played in other locations too.

I tried on [Drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/1365664) first, but I got no answer; any help would be appreciated.

If there's no way to "bind" it to Ubercart, I'd solve it in another way (PayPal IPN), but I have to do it ASAP.

P.S.: I've already tried [MERCI](http://drupal.org/project/merci), [Simple Reservation](http://drupal.org/project/simple_reservation), [Hotel Booking System for Ubercart](http://drupal.org/project/uc_hotel) and [**Reservation**](http://drupal.org/project/reservation) modules (the latter seemed OK from the picture), but unfortunately I couldn't figure out how to do something similar to  what I need - **BUT THIS MEANS NOTHING, maybe I just overlooked some opportunities!**!!

If you say I can solve it with one of these modules, please help! Even if you have a totally different suggestion! Thanks!

---

UPDATE:

In the meantime I found this very interesting article: [Ubercart Event Registration](http://openconcept.ca/comment/1738)
Let me quote from it:

> at the moment, the de facto Ubercart method for doing online event
>   registration is with a module called **[UC Node Checkout](http://drupal.org/project/uc_node_checkout)**. **It's perfect
>   for a one-and-done event registration site, but for a site that is
>   hosting several events simultaneously and on an ongoing basis, it's
>   awkward.** This is due to the fact that it maps a content type to a
>   product SKU - so for each event you'd need to create a new content
>   type. Not really very good long-term, particularly when the site
>   administrator is not overly familiar with Drupal or Ubercart.
>
> So, an alternative solution was devised using the Webforms module. The
>   webform stores the registrant's organization's information - and also
>   asks the registrant how many tickets to the event they want, which is
>   the use case the client specified. The webform, after processing the
>   form, adds the event 'tickets' to the cart. This is done with the
>   'Webform advanced settings' field in the webform configuration, under
>   'Additional Processing'.

Good to know. This means [the article I found earlier](http://drupaleasy.com/blogs/ultimike/2009/03/event-registration-ubercart) doesn't describe what I need.

Another quote from [uc_event_registration's readme](https://github.com/bobchristenson/uc_event_registration):

> **UC Node Checkout**
>
> This is the approach that has been used alot for Drupal conferences
>   and demo'd at drupalcons.  The huge problem here is twofold:  First,
>   registrations are nodes.  That means we have to build views to create
>   registration lists and that seems like unnecessary overhead when
>   **Webform is so much lighter weight**.  Second, and most importantly, **you
>   need a new content type for EVERY event**.  No thanks.  On sites that
>   are doing dozens of events per year, this would mean, eventually, a
>   **huge amount of content types**.  That's bad.

Here's another one related to Webforms: [Drupal Webforms With Dynamic Select Boxes Tutorial](http://www.commercialprogression.com/blog/drupal-webforms-with-dynamic-select-boxes-tutorial)
This seems very promising, maybe this could be the way one could solve what [Andy suggested](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/17375/2368).
I'm still interested in suggestions for practical solutions - maybe this way!

Comment: There's now an awful lot on this page counting comments and answers and I can't quite process it all! How are you doing? Do you still have questions?

Comment: Finally I decided to write my own module, because it seems like unfortunately I will not be able to do this whole thing with the existing modules. Which complicates the situation is that I realized when reserving a seat, I don't have to pay for just one person (with a PayPal account), I'd rather have to let it be payed for the location's owner (or a person who should get the money for tickets). I don't know how I will do that (e.g. on an ebay, every user has their own PayPal-account). :\ I hope I can publish a finished version that I made - maybe this could be shared with the community.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you are going to find a solution that does 100% of what you need, I expect there will need to be custom development here.

Sounds like a custom content type (CCK) + ubercart + paypal (with ubercart) will be the most flexible solution. Perhaps read through the reservation module to see how it limits the available supply of tickets (i.e. sold out).

I would also suggest to remove the graphical part of the event registation, as this looks like it could be tricky, and instead focus on the *core* functionality of the app, i.e. the registration and payment workflow.

Every problem can be solved in drupal, but some of them are unique, and have their own solution.

If you need this solved ASAP, looks like you may need contractors, or some late nights ;) If you want to attract more quality answers, consider placing a bounty on this

Comment: @wiifm: +1, thanks for your quick answer!! Yes, I already know I have to do some custom development, but to be more specific, what kind of custom content type do you think of (within CCK)? I will have to create a relatively simple admin surface too, where I thought I could place some text areas where the user could set the total amount of tables in the place, and narrowing this one by one how many seats there are around the tables. I can think of some possible solutions in my head with my own codes, but I would have to "marry" them to Drupal, which is not a simple task I think...

Comment: (to place a bounty on it, I have to wait one more day. I know even a hundred points of mine wouldn't lead to a half-complete solution, but how nice this would be... :P But maybe I will try.) Oh, and what is not an easy job, I have to maintain a stock not to let users be able to reserve seats that already have been reserved...and let them pay via PayPal.

Comment: I've already placed a bounty on it... hope someone will have time to give me a really detailed help...

Answer (score 2):

I agree with other answers in that you wouldn't get 100% of the way there without some custom development.

My first thought on solving this is don't worry too much about the interface, just get the data entities right. I think your products really only need two new fields at its most basic (venue, which could be a node reference and date (or another node reference to an event content type and reuse events)). Use stock to be the number of tickets available at a venue for an event and product kit could be a table which is just made up of the individual seats and would therefore manage stock and could also have discounts associated with it.

As far as interface goes you could create a calendar view of "seats" and "tables" (tables are just product kit).

**EDIT**: To distill the gist of the comment thread on this I'm going to summarise here.

What we seem to have got to is the following:

- A particular event at a particular venue is a product class/content
  type. These content types all have one CCK field, the event date.
- When you create a new instance of this product class you specify the
  date and add ONE attribute to it, that is the table number. The
  values of this attribute correspond to the number of tables to the
  event.

The workflow this describes is that a customer chooses to add an event to the cart, and as part of this process they have to choose a seat number and a number of seats that they want.

This allows a couple of things:

- You can actually price tables differently,
- You can manage stock at a per table level.

This is because an attribute, straight out of the box, has its own SKU and therefore its own stock levels and own pricing. If you think of what attributes are for this makes sense. If you have red and blue shirts you need to know how much of each you have, i.e. stock levels. If large shirts cost more than small shirts then you have to know how to price them.

Keep in mind this only describes the workflow and the backend. Webforms as described in other answers can still be used to control the interface, as could a custom built form. This is just to manage the data entities. You still have to create events manually but I think in this case the small number of content types is a good thing, and a process could be put together pretty quickly to automate some of this (look at [Node Import](http://drupal.org/project/node_import) for this, it can with some other contrib modules handle attributes as well if you wanted to customise the values)

Some notes:

An interface that works in this instance is a simple view of your new content types (split them by venue if you want as each content type is venue specific) with a link to the actual product. Then you can select a date and a number of tables. If you want to book seats at different tables then you will need to add another product to the cart.

The module [UC Attribute Stock](http://drupal.org/project/ubercart_attribute_stock) isn't really relevant here I think. As far as I can tell it just combines multiple attributes into one selection. That is given the example above of red and blue colours and small and large sizing, rather than have two dropdowns that the customer has to select from you have one drop down with four selections.

The webform solutions are not precluded from anything above. They are providing the interface, and may make sense if there is other, NON PRODUCT, data that you want to collect from your registration. Keep in mind though that you may be able to collect this from the checkout pane a bit more easily and in line with current shopping workfow. I think writing a form though, especially if you want it to have some smarter widgets on the front of it will be easier and lighter in the long run than shoe horning webform into what you want to do. For the basic workflow I don't think you even need it.

Comment: +1: thanks for your answer! Yes, I thought something similar would be great: locations could be node references; tickets as stock units would be good too. But what if an event (like a concert) is repetitive, but it's like a tour, played on many locations? Do I always have to edit the node references and date fields? And you mentioned tables are product kits - but what if a visitor just wants to reserve 2 seats from a table for 8 people? Unfortunately I have to take care about the admin interface too as the user can only handle the simplest interface (and has no idea about Drupal). Thanks!!

Comment: Hmm. OK, I was suggesting product kit to offer pricing variations for "bulk" seating purchases. But it actually sounds like your actual product is a table, where the stock level is the number of seats at the table. You could mitigate your backend work by making a product class that is  a table for an event at a venue, the only variable then is the date.

Comment: yes, the number of tables per locations is "static" as it doesn't change all the time, it has to be "bound" to a location. So you suggest "making a product class that is a table for an event at a venue" - but what if there are 100 tables at a venue? Should I create 100 nodes from the "Table" content type in this case? :\ Will I bind these with node references to a venue? And if there are e.g. 30 locations with 100 tables each, does it mean I should create 30*100 = 3000 nodes ("tables"), and attach these tables to my "Event" node type via node references? I still don't know the good solution.:(

Comment: I reckon you could make the product class have a static link to the venue, that is you have a product class that is a table at a venue. It does mean lots of nodes. The other option may be have something that represents a table at a venue and an attribute that allows them to select a table, i.e. a drop down with the table number.

Comment: OK, but what happens if an event is repetitive? In this case I had to repeat creating the "Table" content and link to a venue all the time. E.g. there would be a concert 3 times a month in the same location, but the number of tables and seats would always remain the same; and I would like to advertise them a month earlier than the events' date. How would I do it then? Oh, and what about the dates of the events? Should I always attach a new "date" reference field to an event? And then attach the event to a venue, etc.? Sorry for asking so much, but I'm still lost in the task.Thx 4 your answers!

Comment: The main problem with a date is that it must be a CCK field, it can't be an attribute like a table can. Multiple nodes aren't an issue, if you can create them manually now, then it isn't a big deal to write something that just creates new nodes for you. So if there's a concert 3 times a month at a venue, then you would have 3x products, with table as an attribute and each with a date reference field. The end goal I think is that if you can get the workflow going, even if there is a lot done manually, you can automate that later. If you can't get the workflow going then you have a problem.

Comment: So you say "with table as an attribute", but there can be many-many tables (say e.g. 100) - e.g. 100 tables would mean 100 attributes? OK, let's say I do this - but in this case should I create a product class in Ubercart for one venue (e.g. Example Bar would be a content type this way), attach e.g. 100 attributes (if there are 100 tables at the venue), and repeat creating this product content type each time a new event occurs? But it's still a question how can I "bind" a stock to table attributes (stock is needed to know how much free seats remained). What do you think?

Comment: No no, one attribute with a select list of numbers 1 - 100 or however many tables are available at the event. You can even have stock based on the attribute (the number of seats at the table)

Comment: I found **UC Attribute Stock** (http://drupal.org/project/ubercart_attribute_stock), but it's unfortunately for Drupal 7, but I would need sg. similar for Drupal 6 - how can I maintain a stock of attributes then? So, just to clarify, you mean: there's a product class, which is an event - required attributes would be tied to it; an attribute would be ONE table. One table attribute can have e.g. a select list of 1-5, if it has 5 free seats available. The second would have e.g. 3, because there are 3 free seats available. And etc. till say 100... Did I understand your answer correctly?

Comment: I don't think you need that module as you can do everything you need with one attribute (table number) with stock maintained for each table. All that module does, looking at it quickly, is combine two attributes into one selection.

Comment: Maybe I still misunderstand you, so please be a little more specific. :) You say "everything you need with one attribute (table number)" - OK, and how can I handle how many seats there are around one given table? I don't know exactly what you mean - there's a possibility that one table is one attribute, and all the unique seats are the attribute's options... But it's a bit hard to maintain. Maybe you suggest something else, but this way don't keep it to yourself :))

Comment: OK, this comment is getting a little bit long, so have updated original question.

Comment: "When you create a new instance of this product class you specify the date and add ONE attribute to it, that is the table number. The values of this attribute correspond to the number of tables to the event." - yes, this would be really simple if I didn't have to provide users the opportunity to select WHICH tables they would like to reserve, and how many seats of the GIVEN TABLE they would like. But as far as I understand you, you consider the problem simpler than it is. I think tables should be like "groups" which have their own stock levels.

Comment: A venue can have e.g. 50 tables. The user would see an interface where he/she could reserve for example the T34 tablw with 4 seats and the T35 table with 10 seats. These would be "static" and "fixed", the location's tables wouldn't be reordered very often.

Comment: But you can have stock at the attribute level, which is why I'm suggesting it. T34 would have a stock level of 4, and T35 would have a stock level of 10. You can even call them "Table One" or whatever you want. You can then get seats (in Ubercart as it stands) on different products by selecting two products with different attributes.

Comment: OK, let's be a bit more specific. If I want to add attributes to a product, first I have to create selectable attributes like this: http://i.imgur.com/Gmtr8.png . Here I could add further ones. An attribute should have options like this: http://i.imgur.com/enaH9.png . I created a test product class, which is not shippable and the default price is 10€s. When I go to "Attributes", I have to first add them: http://i.imgur.com/y7S5P.png, after that: http://i.imgur.com/7kyMJ.png . OK, the product looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/yvGHt.png . (have to continue in next comment, sorry)

Comment: In Adjustments, I can change SKUs not to be the same as in the beginning: http://i.imgur.com/pbr2V.png . After that, I can set stock levels: http://i.imgur.com/CgKXT.png . OK, seems to be ready... but on the product's view, everything remained the same as the first linked image with attributes. The user can't even see how much of the products with given attributes remained. How then? Do you think an option (like here the "1st option of 1st attribute", 2nd.., etc.) should be a table's name? You say "the small number of content types is a good thing" - but this would mean as many as locations.

Comment: One more thing: these attributes are "global", available from all products. Should I create unique attributes for all the locations (with as many OPTIONS as many tables there are)? I would be really grateful if you could illustrate these examples as I did. :) Btw. I think this is a really uncomfortable process, and I don't know how to automate it for a user who has nothing to do with Drupal. :\

Comment: (just one more comment to this: thank you very much for your patience and your kind answers, it's good that people can count on people like you and the others who answered here on Drupal Stack Exchange!)

Comment: Attributes would only need to be defined once. I would lean towards having a separate set of "table" attributes for each venue.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach to the others. You could use [Ubercart Event Registration](http://drupal.org/project/uc_event_registration) for the individual registration forms, and the custom coding could just be a custom webform widget (see [webform_hooks.php](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--webform--webform_hooks.php/6) and the files in the *components* directory for more details). This would be responsible for showing only available places, and reserving the selected place on submission. If you saw a reason, you could integrate the component with one of the reservation modules you mention above. I don't think this is much less work than the alternatives, but it's a slightly different model in that it uses webform. (And I agree entirely with Malks that you want to first decide about how it's going to be handled internally.)

**More details**:
I think there's a number of ways you can do it, depending on for example whether you want to integrate with an existing module, whether you want to use nodes (can be great for quickly making reports with Views), etc. Here's a very brief description of how you might do it with an entirely bespoke implementation.

Assumptions: a single reservation consists of a date, and any positive number of seat IDs.

1. Create a module that provides a webform component for the reservation.
2. The module should also create a DB table for storing reservation details.
3. To begin with forget about a fancy widget, just make it simple (eg. have a textfield for the date, and another for the seat IDs - they can be entered as a comma separated list at first).
4. On validation, the webform component checks with the DB table that the values are valid (ie not already reserved).
5. On submission, the webform component again checks if the reservation is available, and if so makes the reservation. You want to be careful here that two users submitting a request at the same time can't make the same reservation (eg. use a lock in your submit handler).
6. Go back to your widget and make it fancy, eg. have a nice JS date picker that only shows dates with remaining reservations, maybe with some semi-graphical tables that show available seats and let you select them neatly. But underneath it's all basically doing the same thing.

I've not tried something quite like this, so just an idea!

This is still a very simple system, and as it stands it's not very easy to get the data out. You might want to make some bespoke admin screens or you could views enable your db table.

You don't want to use this approach unless you want the idea of one node per form, with submissions being stored in the webform submitted data table. You really want to be sure that this fits your needs before taking this path imho.

Comment: +1: it seems to be a very good approach too, thank you! But if you don't mind, let me ask to clarify I understood you correctly: the form for showing available places and letting them be selected would be a "separate" webform, which on submission would update the available places and decrement them; and this "event registration" webform is one that can be bound to Ubercart. Is it correct? And how could this webform be built up? And yes, all of you are right that I have to find out first HOW I would do this whole thing... that's why it's very good you all help me think about it. Thx in advance!

Comment: hmm, I still haven't figure out how to solve it with webforms - e.g. how to maintain a stock of seats. (So one table would have a stock of the available seats.) Could you push me a little bit further with your approach?

Comment: @Sk8erPeter Updated anwer

Comment: thanks for the updated answer! I also have to "categorize" seats to tables. So the best would be to have tables e.g. like this: T1 - 4 seats, T2 - 6 seats, ..., Tn - 3 seats, etc. I understand the theory of what you say, I can imagine something similar, but I still don't know the adequate Drupal-way solutions *in practice*. E.g. you didn't mention the problem of recurring events - what should I do with date fields? Should I pass a new date field to a content type every time a new event is coming? What about the same event - new location problem? Date+location would be tied together. Thx again!

Comment: I updated my question, please see the new infos under the line! I think "you're tha man" :D, because you suggested webforms from the beginning - I think this seems to be the best approach so far! Do you have experience with similar solutions, anything related to webforms+products?

Comment: @Sk8erPeter I do have experience of webform products (I'm the maintainer of uc_event_registration), but not of anything as complex as what you're attempting! I'm afraid today's my last day of work this year so v. busy, and off to the Netherlands for the weekend tomorrow morning, so won't be able to look at your update before next week.

Comment: wow, it sounds good that you're the maintainer of this great module! I think using UC Node Checkout with a node that is bound to a custom reservation Webform is very similar to an approach of using uc_event_registration with the same custom reservation Webform. So I "just" have to find out HOW to create this customized webform, and attach it to the "Paid Event" product: I have to learn webform-developing... but I'm much further than at the beginning. If you have hints good links related to similar custom webform creations, please share them, I would appreciate it. :) Have a good trip!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should make table as a product.

We've this relationship:
event1 -> date1 -> city1 -> restraunt1 -> table1

So 1 refers to 1-many relationship.

Have Venue table with information about each venue and tables and other attributes

Have City table with city + venue details

Have OrderBooking table with this:
event1,date1,city1,venu-id,product-id

Customer will browse from event to restraunt and will see available seats(products). Write a module to display the (availability) details along with links to create a product. As soon as one clicks a link in the venue, arrange for a pop up which will ask for table specific details and direct to product form and auto populate the product with those details in a custom cck field. Now when tries to buy the product then you should write a module to check availability and after payment have this product related to the OrderBooking table.

You'll need to use UC Node Checkout module as described [here](http://drupaleasy.com/blogs/ultimike/2009/03/event-registration-ubercart) for collecting registration data.

I've taken a simplistic view.

Comment: +1: thanks. I also thought much about the theory of the whole process, I've already drawn a diagram of table relationships, but I'm interested in **practical** todos. By the way your link is the same as the one I also posted on drupal.org: http://drupal.org/node/1365664 , but collecting user data is maybe the easiest part of the whole thing. I'm curious about the easiest practical solution of the problem - maybe the modules I linked are suitable for the task, I just didn't find out how to do it. And I still don't know to make an event recurrent (passing newer date field, etc.??). Thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to an article which states UC Node Checkout is a little bit overkill for tasks like this. What's your opinion about it?

Comment: It isn't. It is easy to configure and is very useful. I've done for my site, try adding this product in the cart: http://www.utilitiesindia.com/send-letter-online-india . This will allow you to associate any type of Node(in your case, receive any custom registration data, before selecting a table) with a checked out product. Great thing is that it works seamlessly and integrates well with product checkout workflow. Also I'm not aware of any improvements in this module in last 10 months. So checkout.

Comment: Although I'm not an expert in Ubercart, I think that custom solution will be simple, flexible and easy to maintain. Ubercart does not provide the functionality you're looking for. Using "techniques" to use Ubercart functions in different( like using Tables as attributes) way will mess up the logic and workflow.

Comment: +1 for your comment, thanks for the example! It gave me an idea: maybe this way I could create an Event product type with a "Location" node reference (description and address of the venue) and a date field; change the "Add to cart" submit button's text to "Buy tickets"; and after the user submits the form, I could attach another node with UC Node Checkout, where I would display a custom reservation Webform node. With this form, the user could select which table and how many seats he/she would like to reserve. With this number I would have to decrement the available seats for the given table.

Comment: (sorry, too much characters, I have to continue here:) The reservation tables would be my own db-tables - with table ids + available free seats + happening ids + location ids tied together. I just have to find out how to create a customized webform like this... On the admin interface, admin would create a Location content type, type in how many tables there are -> after this, I would have to generate so much fields, and let the admin set how many seats there are around a table - it would default to 1, admin could change it. After that, he types address. Do you think this concept is OK?

Comment: Do you have any diagram -- this'd immensly help all of us to understand your perspective. You can make one your raw design along with pros, cons and clarifications you need. This should be very useful for your site design.

Comment: I surely will post the diagram, I just have to think about it again if the plans are viable. Until that, I updated my question again with another quote of uc_event_registration module's readme which states it's a bad thing to have a new content type for every new events, which I would need for UC Node Checkout. I think there's some truth in it. Or I don't need new content types for it? I already can't see the wood for the trees. I'll notify you as soon as I managed to make a draft of my plans!

Comment: Without fully understanding what's going on I want to suggestion something. Remove Location from your design as it is very trivial issue and will not affect current site design. Secondly use Ubercart only for the functionality it provides. Don't create too many products if they are all similar like Tables or Events. Make buyable items like Ticket a product. Don't think about UC Node Checkout either. First make it in natural way, then let us think what Drupal functionality/modules are available to do them in easier way. If there are, it's good otherwise you develop it.

Comment: OK, Location doesn't affect "site design", but I have to attach the Location to an event to let the users know where an event will occur. And yepp, I thought about creating a Ticket product class in Ubercart (which creates "Ticket" content type), which users can buy, but they also would have to select for which event they would like to buy a ticket (to an event, there would be a date field attached - when it happens) - and which seats/tables they would like to reserve. Creating a Ticket product doesn't mean a problem...my only obstacle to being ready is to solve the **reservation** problem.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar for a tour agency. I used the [Hotel Booking](http://drupal.org/project/uc_hotel) module for Ubercart, each event is a "room" which you can set a limit for occupancy and charge differently depending on the day. On the admin side, you have calendars you can select what days are available on a recurring basis. I believe you can have different kinds of [events] as well.

The only issue was it was new in Drupal 7 and had a few bugs, but it may have improved by now.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following module: [Booking Time Slots](http://drupal.org/project/booking_timeslots).

As the name says, it provides Time Slots Booking functionality. It integrates with Views and Calendar.

Check the sample screenshot in Drupal 7.x:

[image: Drupal 7.x - Booking Time Slots]

For more, check [Comparison of Booking System modules](http://groups.drupal.org/node/137544).